# Asp.net core Log4net logging messages are over-writing in the log file on every time Running the application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using log4net in Asp.Net core Application.I am able to save the data to the log file .But the issue is every time I run the application, old data erases and new messages are logging.I want to append the logs.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Keeping this Property  set to True in log4net config works for me !

```
<appendToFile value="true" />
```